# How to get HTML code compatibility for old / modern browsers

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, fonts

I am using [Material Icons](https://design.google.com/icons/) font, with AngularJS, for a Cordova Android/iOS app.

Problem is, for some Android 4.X versions, I have to use the "old" way to display icon, like this (code from the documentation) :

```
<!-- For modern browsers. -->
<i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
<!-- For IE9 or below. -->
<i class="material-icons">&#xE5C4;</i>
```

So now, I think I have to find every icons in my project, and update the icon text by the hexa one, but before that I have some questions :

**Questions :**

- Is it safe (or a bad practice) to *only* use the old way (`&#xE5C4;`) to display icons, even for modern browsers ? Is this compatibility will be dropped in few years by modern browsers ?
- Is there a good way (in AngularJS, pure JS or HTML, if possible) to detect if the browser dosen't support the modern way, and then, replace the icon text by some hexa (`arrow_back` -> `&#xE5C4;`)

Comment: I don't see why browsers would drop support for `&#xE5C4;`.

Comment: So using hexadecimal is the right solution ? I won't get any problem in future with that ?

Comment: You should be fine with the hexadecimal format. (You might also be able to test if the modern way's supported by the current browser, and if not fall back to hexadecimal, but it's probably easier just to use hexadecimal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use hexadecimal solution, it works, but it is a pain when you read your HTML, so I have found an other solution : generate icons via classname.

It works great, so I just created a repository if anyone had the same problem : [material-icons-css](https://github.com/JCornat/material-icons-css)